# Something is automatically creating .css & .css.map files when I save a file I want to import with into a sass file

Tags: css, import, sass, sublimetext

I'm saving files as `_import.scss` and importing them into a main Sass file using `@import "import"`. However, when I save these import files, *something* is automatically creating files called `_import.css` and `_import.css.map`.

I have no idea how this is happening. I'm using Sublime Text, and I have the Sass, Compass, and Bourbon gems installed on my system. However, there's no `sass --watch` running in my command line. How are these files being generated automatically and how do I stop it? I just want the main file to import the files and *only then* create a `.css` file from that one file.

My project directory looks somewhat like this:

```
- project
    - scss
        _import1.scss     /* these files are to be imported */
        _import2.scss
        _import3.scss
        style.scss        /* this is where the imports go */
    index.html
    style.css             /* the ONLY file I want generated automatically
                             (from scss/style.scss) */
```

Basically I just want to run `sass --watch scss/style.scss:style.css` without generating a huge clutter of files from my imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, okay. Five minutes after typing this out I found the answer myself. I feel stupid. Anyways, the *something* creating these files was Sublime Text's packages 'Sass Build' and 'Sass Build on Save' which I installed ages ago and completely forgot about.